# Disk Partitioning Combining volumes

Tags: windows, partitioning

Current Partitions:

[image: Current Partitions]

I want to combine `BOOTCAMP`(C:) to `NewVolume` (G:), but when I click on `BOOTCAMP` the option to expand is greyed out. Need advice

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot expand a volume or partition when there is no unallocated space on the disk. You would need to create some unallocated space on the disk to expand `BOOTCAMP`, by deleting or shrinking another partition.

Comment: Use [EaseUse partition master](http://www.partition-tool.com/) to merge two successive partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only expand into *empty* space that's immediately to the right of the partition you want to extend.

In your specific scenario you'll need to delete G:, and then move the 620MB and C: partitions all the way left, leaving the empty space to the left (behind) the Bootcamp C: drive.

You can then extend/expand the C: drive into the empty space.

You won't be able to do the partition moves using in-built Windows disk utilities, so you'll need to get a 3rd party Partition Editor (like [GPartEd](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php), perhaps) to perform the repartitioning work.

Ensure you have a full backup before messing with disk partitions, and don't be surprised of it takes many minutes to several hours to complete the moves (depending on how much data needs shifting, disk speeds, etc.).

Comment: Thanks I followed your advice, and with a few heart stopping moments, it went off without a hitch. Thanks so much

Comment: No problem, glad it worked, and welcome to SU!  Feel free to mark this answer (or another, if you so desire) as Accepted -- it keeps the question from appearing unresolved. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 is correct; however, I want to add more:

Your `C:` partition is called `BOOTCAMP`, and this implies that your computer is a Mac on which you're dual-booting Windows and OS X. Many -- but by no means all -- such systems use a [hybrid MBR,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) which is an ugly and ***DANGEROUS*** hack. The point of a hybrid MBR is to enable older versions of Windows (Windows 7 and earlier) to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode from what they interpret as an MBR disk, even though OS X is installed in EFI mode from what it interprets as a GPT disk. These two partition table types (MBR and GPT) do not normally coexist on one disk, but a hybrid MBR is a way to make them do so.

The trouble is that, if you use a partitioning tool that adjusts one partition table but not the other, the two can get out of sync, which means that the disk can have overlapping partitions. This is easy to do if you use the standard Windows partitioning tools, which will adjust the MBR side but not the GPT side. The GParted tool that Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 recommended will adjust the GPT side and then wipe out the hybrid MBR, which is actually safer, since then at least everything is consistent -- but you'll need to re-create the hybrid MBR, if you'd been using one. Knowing the details of the current hybrid MBR setup *before* you wipe it out will help you re-create it in the future.

Thus, before you begin, I strongly advise you to first figure out whether you've got a straight-up GPT disk, a straight-up MBR disk, or a GPT disk with a hybrid MBR. If you've got a hybrid MBR, it's imperative that you understand this format and know how to safely manipulate it. Read my page on hybrid MBRs (referenced earlier; it's part of my GPT fdisk [`gdisk`] software's documentation) for the basics. Keep reading until you understand, and practice on a "scratch" disk, if necessary. I've seen too many posts from people who've trashed their hybrid MBR setups and who've barely recovered, or been unable to recover, as a result.

Comment: I was dual booting but came home to Windows. I did not like the Apple environment nor their applications. I saw no discernible difference between Win and OS X that made me say "So glad I switched".

Comment: If you simply deleted the Mac partitions, you may well still have a GPT with a hybrid MBR. In that case, if you care *only* about the Windows partitions on the MBR side, you could convert the disk to a straight-up MBR configuration. OTOH, you might already have such a configuration, or it might be plain GPT with EFI-mode booting. It's impossible to say without seeing partition table details. Be aware that not all partitioning tools show the relevant details. The `gdisk` print operation will.